# jQuery plugin "Crossbrowser Html5 Black and white jQuery plug in"

Tags: jquery

I been trying all day to get this plugin "Crossbrowser Html5 Black and white jQuery"
plug in to work...

Link to the source (plugin),
http://gianlucaguarini.com/canvas-experiments/jQuery.BlackAndWhite/demo.html

Link to my test page,
http://viwwi.se/jQueryBlackAndWhite/

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You need to provide much much more detail in your question if you want to avoid your question being closed.  Try to explain what your problem is rather than simply providing a link to the page.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error console on your page:

```
GET http://viwwi.se/jQueryBlackAndWhite/js/BnWWorker.js 404 (Not Found) jQuery.BlackAndWhite.js:79
```